# Erro de sintaxe no if else

Tags: python

```
frase1 = str(input("Digite uma frase: ").strip())
frase2 = str(input("Digite uma frase: ").strip())

print("O tamanho da frase1 é " ,len(frase1))
print("O tamanho da frase2 é " ,len(frase2))
if frase1 == frase2:
    print("SÃO IGUAIS")
    else:  //INVALID SYNTAX
        print("SÃO DIFERENTES")
```

O quê pode estar errado no código?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A indentação do `else` está errada. Ele deveria estar no mesmo nível que o `if`:

```
frase1 = str(input("Digite uma frase: ").strip())
frase2 = str(input("Digite uma frase: ").strip())

print("O tamanho da frase1 é " ,len(frase1))
print("O tamanho da frase2 é " ,len(frase2))

if frase1 == frase2:
    print("SÃO IGUAIS")
else:
    print("SÃO DIFERENTES")
```

Lembre-se que toda a análise sintática no Python acontece baseando-se na indentação. Se colocar o `else` dentro do bloco do `if`, o interpretador irá considerar que ele é um bloco lógico independente que será executado se a condição no `if` for verdadeira. Como o `else` não é um bloco válido (sem o `if`), um erro de sintaxe é disparado. O mesmo problema pode acontecer com outros blocos, como o próprio `if`:

```
if frase1 == frase2:
     print("São iguais")
     if frase1 != frase2:
         print("São diferentes")
```

Neste caso, não seria gerado um erro de sintaxe, mas se o segundo `if` devesse ser fora do primeiro, o resultado do programa seria diferente do esperado - isto é, mesmo que as frases fossem diferentes, nenhuma saída seria gerada. Ou seja, **tome muito cuidado com a indentação sempre**.

Comment: Desculpa a "noobice" mas o Python não deveria indentar automaticamente?

Comment: Não. A linguagem não tem esse poder e nem deveria ter, pois toda a lógica da aplicação é construída sobre a indentação. No máximo o editor de texto que usa tenha alguma ferramenta que auxilia na indentação, mas é completamente independente da linguagem.

Comment: Anderson, voce é um mito. Muito obrigado pela ajuda

Answer (score 3):

O problema é que o else está tabulado, o correto seria:

```
frase1 = str(input("Digite uma frase: ").strip())
frase2 = str(input("Digite uma frase: ").strip())

print("O tamanho da frase1 é " ,len(frase1))
print("O tamanho da frase2 é " ,len(frase2))
if frase1 == frase2:
    print("SÃO IGUAIS")
else:
    print("SÃO DIFERENTES")
```